# Disable gzip on WordPress

Tags: compression

I can see WordPress enables Gzip compression on the site
I disabled all plugins to ensure that no plugin enabled that
And also I created a simple php script and it doesn't enable gzip by default by Web Server
So I think WordPress enable Gzip in it's code
How can I prevent WordPress to enable Gzip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check `.htaccess` on `/home/` and `/homr/public_html/` (For example of site root), Probably there are some codes there to add gzip to the web server
2. a web server can enable the gzip as default
3. check `php.ini` file for `zlib.output_compression` value, It should be off